# How to add HTML tag into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make use of one html tag into my javascript but don't know how to make use of that.

For ex: `<p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a></p>`

This is my tag. I want to store this into some variable so I can make use of that later in my function. But I don't how to store it. On way I got to store like

```
var htm = { html : <p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a></p>}
```

But again this is an object I can not use the perticular anchor tag. Can anybody please suggest how to deal with it. How to store html tags in JavaScript variable or any solutions.

Comment: Save it as string, then you can append it to somewhere. But what do you want to do with it?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: `var html = '<p>Test</p>'` ... I don't really get what you mean otherwise? HTML would just be a string? What do you mean by "use the anchor tag"?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal Whatever I tried I pasted.

Comment: @maximelian1986 I want to use of anchor tag in my email body. So far I am able to add plane text which I store in variable. But for url I want to use anchor tag.

Comment: @David On the other hand, whom soever using it should render this as html.

Comment: @ANS can you please give one example or link, so it will help me to understand.

Answer (score 4):

```js
    
function createCustomElement(anchorText, anchorLink){
  

  var aTag = document.createElement("a");
  aTag.href = anchorLink;
  aTag.innerHTML = anchorText;
  
  return aTag ;
}

var parent = document.getElementById('para');
var customElement = createCustomElement("w3Schools", "www.w3School.com");
parent.appendChild(customElement);
```

```html
<div id="para">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is I can try. One question where should I write `<div id="para">
</div>`.

Comment: It can be any parent element to which you want to add you <p></p>

Comment: Ok Sure I am trying this.

Comment: Ya I am using only a tag. No need for para. But don't know for some reason it is showing only url. no anchor text. I am debugging. once I get success, I will accept the answer.

Comment: Okay made the changes according to the new requirement

Comment: Ya I changed that. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138193/discussion-between-arunbabuvijayanath-and-david).

Answer (score 3):

We can assign the string template directly by calling innerHTML on a newly created element and returning its childNode. By doing so we can add custom attributes to the new DOM element as well by adding it to the template string.

```js
function strToElem(text, link){
  var temp = '<p> An absolute URL : <a href="'+ link + '">'+text+'</a></p>';
  var a = document.createElement("p");
  a.innerHTML = temp;
  return a.childNodes[0];
}

var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var elem = strToElem("w3Schools", "www.w3School.com");
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but applying this I am getting only link not text

Comment: Updated the code. Just change the template to suit your needs. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible and you can store it as String. If you are struggling to make it work because of the quotes confusion, correct would be

```
var htm = { html : '<p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a></p>'}
```

*Note the single quotes. Since you already used doubles quotes for href, you string must wrapped with single quotes.*

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code. Enclose your html block of code in '' and it should work.

`var test = '<p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a></p>';`

Comment: But I want to be anchor tag functionality. This is working as plane string

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to enclose that html in '  ' (for correct sitaxis) , or,  second option is create an Dom object using Javascript.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Then you can edit and modify as a real html not a simple string.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can get it as a element:

var el = document.getElementById('something');

and use it in your function

there's two way to get the elemete;

-------one way------

in html

```
  <p id="something">An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a></p>
```

in js

```
var el = document.getElementById('something');
```

----the other way----

create a element by js

```
  var el =  document.createElement("p");
```

[this is how to use the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: Thanks. I read this but not sure where should I write my html code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create html element as objects in JavaScript using `document.createElement()` method,

To create and store following html string in JavaScript as an object:
`<p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a></p>`

You will first need to create parent `<p>` tag as follows,

```
var ptag = document.createElement('p');
ptag.innerText = 'An absolute URL:';
```

Next you will need to create anchor tag object as follows,

```
var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
anchroTag.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com';
anchorTag.innerText = 'w3Schools';
```

Next append anchor tag as child to `<p>` tag as follows,

```
ptag.appendChild(anchorTag);
```

This way now you can refer your object `ptag` and `anchorTag` latter.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I drop the idea of ptag. Using only `atag`. I am getting the url, not `anchorText`. there should be innerHTML or `anchorTag.innerText`

Comment: For RichtText you need yo use .innerHtml and for plain text you can use .innerText. You can use .innerHtml.

Comment: For more details on setting and getting anchor text have a look at following page,
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_text.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='container'>
    <h1>Hi mama</h1>
</div>

<script>
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    container.innerHTML += "<h1> hi dad</h1>"; 
</script>

//result
<div class='container'>
        <h1>Hi mama</h1>
        <h1> hi dad</h1>
    </div>
```