# Adding html tags inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am trying to add `<button id="mybtn"></button>` around the `some text` link but I am not sure how to make it.  I tried a bit with `document.write` but I think I am using it wrong.  When I click this button `some text` it replaces 'ZZZ' with nothing.  However the changed link `something here` has a plain formatting.  What I want it to do is add the `<button id="mybtn">` and`</button>` around it, so the changed button stays with the same look.

Input:

```
document.getElementById("DiacriticsButton").innerHTML = "some text";
```

Output should be something like:

```
document.getElementById("DiacriticsButton").innerHTML = <button id="mybtn">"some text"</button>;
```

The current full script:

```
<script>
bodyText=document.getElementById("bodytext").innerHTML;
clearText = bodyText.replace(/ZZZ/g, "");
FStr = clearText.search("some text");

do {
  clearText = clearText.replace("something here","some text");  
  FStr = clearText.search("something here");
}
while(FStr!=-1);

function switchDiacritics() {
  if (document.getElementById("bodytext").innerHTML == clearText) {
    document.getElementById("bodytext").innerHTML = bodyText;
    document.getElementById("DiacriticsButton").innerHTML = "something here";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("bodytext").innerHTML = clearText;
    document.getElementById("DiacriticsButton").innerHTML = "some text";
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828098/how-to-add-html-tag-into-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you look for something like this

```
document.getElementById("DiacriticsButton").innerHTML = '<button id="mybtn">"some text"</button>';
```

It is also possible to add element like this

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "some text";
document.getElementById("DiacriticsButton").appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything to trigger this innerHTML change? Ex:

Wrapping the selection in `window.onLoad{...}`

OR

Wrapping it in a function to be triggered by an event listener. While if your goal is to simply place text within the tag in a static demeanour use the HTML attribute for a button with `value="some text"`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've updated the questions and added the whole script.

Comment: So when are you trying to trigger your `switchDiacritics` function? Is it on the pages load or an event listener ex. (click on certain elements).

Comment: triggering it with `<a href="javascript:switchDiacritics()" ID="DiacriticsButton"><button id="mybtn">some text</button></a>`

Comment: You can trigger it by simply placing a `onclick` attribute to your anchor tag: `<a onclick="switchDiacritics()" ID="DiacriticsButton">`, just assure you define the function before it's used.

Comment: Can you edit the code as suggested and post it as an answer, so I can test it and accept the answer?

Comment: That change to the anchor tag should fix your problem I believe

Comment: It didn't work..  When I click this button `some text` it replaces 'ZZZ' with nothing.  However the changed link `something here` has a plain formatting.  What I want it to do is add the `<button id="mybtn">` and`</button>` around it, so the changed button stays with the same look.